# Azure Portal --> Virtual Machine (Default Directory) page issue?

Tags: azure

I am very new to Azure Portal.
I have noticed the following for Subject mentioned page.

Once I open the Virtual machines page

1. The (Assign Tags,Start,Restart, Deleted, Services) are comes to be disable and it should be? as I have not selected any of the VM checkbox.
2. However once I select any of the checkbox then above mentioned buttons are enabled.
3. I deselect the checkbox but buttons remains enabled.
     So, behavior in *1 and *3 is different. I was expecting that buttons shall disable again as I have not selected any VM.

Moreover, I can delete, assign tags etc, even without selecting the VM.

Sorry if this question is not relevant here and please provide any information if my expectation is wrong as I am very new to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

It is an odd user experience, but when you first visit the page (what you described in #1) there are no VMs selected and it has no context.  When you un-check the check box the the row and VM are still selected.  If you initiate one of those actions you will find that the highlighted row is the item you are changing.